# Executar programa com Python: comando "python3" não é reconhecido

Tags: python, windows

Boa tarde,

Estou aprendendo a criar programas na linguagem python e executá-los..

Estou utilizando Windows, mas ao abrir o *Prompt* de comado e digitar `python3 somador.py` a mensagem que gera é:

> "python3" não é reconhecido como comando interno ou externo, um
>   programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

O que eu faço?

Comment: Já tentou "python" ao invés de "python3"?

Comment: Priscila, como você fez a instalação do Python no Windows? Você lembrou de inserir o caminho do executável na variável de ambiente `PATH`?

Comment: Pricila pare de sofrer fazendo builds, verificando problemas de dependências, incompatibilidade de ambiente, baixando distribuições malucas, ... apenas remova as instalações antigas do python e instale o [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/),eu estava quase desistindo do Python e me ensinaram isso por esses dias.(PS: Não tenho nada haver com a empresa)

Answer (score 8):

> - **Update**:

**1)** Baixe uma versão oficial do **[Python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/python-3.8.1-amd64.exe)**

**2)** Use a instalação customizada seguindo os recortes de telas abaixo.

**3)** Execute seu **`somador.py`** direto na linha de comando apenas digitando o nome **`somador.py`**

- **Recorte de tela #1**

  ---

[image]

- **Recorte de tela #2**

  ---

[image]

- **Recorte de tela #3**

  ---

[image]

---

- Eu executo o codigo abixo em **[python](/questions/tagged/python)** apenas digitando **`Q60471933.py`**

  ---

```bat
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
dt = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Hello World", dt) 
# Q60471933.py
```

---

- Outputs:

[image]

---

---

***Postagem anterior***

---

Para usar o seu script/programa **`somador.py`** sugiro checar os possíveis **nomes/caminhos dos executáveis**:

Para verificar o(s) caminho(s) e o(s) nome(s), abra o **`cmd.exe`** e digite:

---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r \ python*.exe
```

---

No meu Windows este comando retorna uma lista com todos os nomes e caminhos:

---

```bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\debugger_2018\python\intel64\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\debugger_2018\python\intel64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython2\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython2\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython2\pkgs\python-2.7.16-10\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython2\pkgs\python-2.7.16-10\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython3\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython3\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython3\pkgs\python-3.6.9-4\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython3\pkgs\python-3.6.9-4\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018\debugger_2018\python\intel64\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018\debugger_2018\python\intel64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018.4.062\debugger_2018\python\intel64\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018.4.062\debugger_2018\python\intel64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier\vpp\server\dist\3rdparty\vpp-python\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier\vpp\server\dist\3rdparty\vpp-python\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier 2019\vpp\server\dist\3rdparty\vpp-python\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier 2019\vpp\server\dist\3rdparty\vpp-python\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\python-3.6.5-h0c2934d_0\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\python-3.6.5-h0c2934d_0\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\pywin32-223-py36hfa6e2cd_1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\pywin32-223-py36hfa6e2cd_1\Lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\pythonw.exe
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\CPython3.Exe.x64,version=3.6.6,chip=x64\python-3.6.6-amd64.exe
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\CPython3.Exe.x64,version=3.6.6,chip=x64\python-3.6.6-amd64.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\KDevelop\python\python.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\KDevelop\python\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{0f40e78b-67e1-4e0c-a2fd-e9325d9dfc82}\python-3.7.2.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{37ec7371-0827-49f1-be8a-63c158184b9c}\python-3.8.0.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{a2e7eb2f-e31e-47eb-82ca-63b3854f5354}\python-3.6.6-amd64.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\pythonw_d.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python_d.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\python.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\python.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\Downloads\python-3.7.2.exe
C:\Users\ecker\Downloads\python-3.8.0.exe
C:\Users\Todos os Usuários\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\CPython3.Exe.x64,version=3.6.6,chip=x64\python-3.6.6-amd64.exe
C:\Windows\Installer\{9255D53C-6C21-4664-AAF3-6EAC50F867DA}\python_icon.exe
```

---

- Para dar uma filtrada e pegar apenas os nomes:

  ---

```bat
python.exe, pytonw.exe, python2.exe python3.exe, python3-2.7.16-10, python-3.6.9-4.exe, python_etc...
```

---

- Apenas altere o **`*`** para **`?`**: 
  **`python*.exe`** para **`python?.exe`**, daí vamos resumir a saída do comando anterior e obter:

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r \ python?.exe
```

---

- Retorna uma lista mais resumida:

  ---

```bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\debugger_2018\python\intel64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython2\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython2\pkgs\python-2.7.16-10\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython3\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\intelpython3\pkgs\python-3.6.9-4\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018\debugger_2018\python\intel64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\parallel_studio_xe_2018.4.062\debugger_2018\python\intel64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier\vpp\server\dist\3rdparty\vpp-python\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier 2019\vpp\server\dist\3rdparty\vpp-python\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\python-3.6.5-h0c2934d_0\pythonw.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\pythonw.exe
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\KDevelop\python\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\pythonw.exe
```

---

- Para dar busca apenas nos caminhos armazenados na variável **`%path%`**, é só substituir:

  ---

  **`/r \ arquivo*.ext`** por **`"%path%:arquivo*.ext"`**, ficando:

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%path%:python?.exe"
```

---

- Me retornando uma lista ainda mais resumida:

  ---

```bat
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
```

---

- **`Python.exe -3`** <sub>x</sub> **`Python.exe -2`**
- **`Py.exe -3`** <sub>x</sub> **`Py.exe -2`**

  ---

  - Sem querer entrar no tema, ainda existe a opção de executar seu código em **`python 2`*** ou em **`python 3`**, apenas usando a flag **`-2`** ou **`-3`**.

O que também pode ser feito, é invocar/usar o **`Py.exe`**, que automaticamente vai selecionar dentre as versões instaladas (provenientes de python.org) no computador, ele pega a mais recente para execução de seu código

---

- Para maiores/precisas informações, consulte nesses links:

**Perguntas Recentes: [Como Usar o Python](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/python/faqs)**

**Python `Py.exe` [Launcher for Windows/en](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)**

---

**Obs.: 1)** Para usar o command **`where.exe`** e procurar em todo o **HD** use:

**`%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r \ arquivo*.ext`**

---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r \ python*.exe
```

---

**Obs.: 2)** Para usar o command **`where.exe`** e procurar apenas na variável **`%path%`** use:

**`where.exe "%path%:arquiv.ext"`**

---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%where.exe "%path%:python*.exe"
```

---

Apenas para testes de caminho, versões e etc... testes esses comandos:

---

```bat
"%windir%\py.exe" somador.py
"%windir%\py.exe" -2 somador.py
"%windir%\py.exe" -3 somador.py
```

---

- O que também costumo fazer para fins de verificar/testar um sistema e checar quais versões do Python estão disponíveis, é um bat hibrido(python + bat):

  ---

```bat
1>2# : ^
'''
@echo off && if exist %windir%\py.exe (
     for %%i in (" " -2 -3)do "%windir%\py.exe" %%~i "%~f0"|%__APPDIR__%find.exe /i "Current Time" 2>nul && (
     echo/ Executou Py.exe %%~i) || (echo/ Py.exe %%~i nao executado)) else (echo/ Py.exe nao encontrado^!! )
goto :EOF
'''
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

---

- A execução me retorna:

  ---

```
Current Time = 16:54:59
 Executou Py.exe 
('Current Time =', '16:54:59')
 Executou Py.exe -2
Current Time = 16:54:59
 Executou Py.exe -3
```

---

- O que retorna da execução significa:

  ---

```
 Executou Py.exe    tenho py.exe e tenho Python 

 Executou Py.exe -2 tenho py.exe e tenho Python 2 

 Executou Py.exe -3 tenho py.exe e tenho Python 3
```

---

---

**[Como usar Python hibrido com bat/cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467441/how-to-embed-python-code-in-batch-script)**

---

Considere o comentário do **[@woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/woss)**...

Adicione o caminho/path do python na variável **`Path`**:

---

Aqui tens um tutorial/En de [como adicionar o python no path](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)

Opcionalmente e não muito recomendável, use o comando abaixo **concatenando** o caminho para o **`drive:\pasta\do\python`** usando o delimitador **`;`**

**`%path%`** +delimitador+**`path_do_python`**

```
set "path=%path%;C:\Python27;C:\Python38;%PATH%"
```

Concatene o caminho do seu python usando o delimitador **`;`** :
 **`%path%`** +delimitador+**`path_do_python`**:

---

Answer (score 4):

Caso já tenha realmente feito a instalação do Python3.x no seu Windows encontre o diretório no qual foi instalado e configure a variável de ambiente PATH.

Veja como está a variável path do meu Windows: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de configurar a variável PATH você precisará fechar e abrir o prompt de comando novamente.

Caso ainda não tenha o Python3.x instalado vá até o site do projeto (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-381/) e baixe a última versão estável.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mais necessário que qualquer voto up/down na pergunta, seria uma resposta para atendimento da dúvida/problema em potencial para qualquer iniciante na linguagem, sua resposta atende para solução onde ações de voto down não solucionaram, uma ação que eh ímpar na plataforma. Prestar apoio/incentivo/propor  solução aos iniciantes.

Comment: Parabéns pela exemplar participação/iniciativa!

Answer (score -8):

No Windows não é necessário dizer qual a versão do Python, basta digitar `python` e o nome do arquivo com a extensão **.py**.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
python somador.py
```

Em ambientes Unix se faz necessário a versão do Python.

Comment: Está errado. Quando há duas versões do Python no Windows, você precisa chama-las com `python` para a 2.x e `python3` para 3.x.